# Count term nodes including child terms nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy with similar structure (only two levels depth)

> - Parent term 1 (3)
>
>   - Child term 1 (5)
>   - Child term 2 (2)
> - Parent term 2
>
>   - Child term

I want to display only parent terms with a node counter for each of them, but I want this counter also include child term nodes

E.g. Lets say **Parent term 1** has 3 nodes assigned to it, **Child term 1** has 5 nodes assigned to it and **Child term 2** has 2 nodes. In this case I want view to display something like this:

> Parent term 1 (10)

Also I don't want to show **Parent term 2** since it doesn't have nodes assigned to it as well as it child

Is it possible through views?